# Calculating a definite integral with variable boundaries in Python

Tags: python, math, sympy, numba, integral

I have been currently working on calculating a definite integral. I need to obtain some numerical outputs, but I cannot. My two attempts to solve the integral are below. **How can I run one of these methods below?**

My first way to calculate the integral is

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

Nt = 17                                         
alpha = .99
t = np.linspace(0, .85, Nt)     
s = np.linspace(0, .85, Nt) 

for k in range(Nt): 
  for i in range(k): 
    Int = integrate( (t[k] - s) ** - int(alpha), (s, t[i], t[i + 1] )) 
    print(Int)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid limits given: ((array([0.      , 0.053125, 0.10625 , 0.159375, 0.2125  , 0.265625,
       0.31875 , 0.371875, 0.425   , 0.478125, 0.53125 , 0.584375,
       0.6375  , 0.690625, 0.74375 , 0.796875, 0.85    ]), 0.0, 0.053125),)
```

My second way is

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from numba import jit, prange

Nt = 17                                        
alpha = .99
t = np.linspace(0, .85, Nt)     
s = np.linspace(0, .85, Nt) 

@jit(nopython=True)
def Int(alpha):
  Int = 0
  for k in prange(Nt): 
    for i in prange(k): 
      Int = Int + integrate( (t[k] - s) ** - int(alpha), (s, t[i], t[i + 1] )) 
      print(Int)   
  return Int
```

There is no any outputs.

**EDIT:** For my first way, I made a small change and got some numerical results. I am not sure about the result. Any comments are still welcome.

```
Nt = 17                                        
alpha = .99
t = np.linspace(0, .85, Nt)     
s = symbols('s')

for k in range(Nt): 
  for i in range(k): 
    Int = integrate((t[k] - s) ** - int(alpha), (s, t[i], t[i + 1] )) 
    print(Int)
```

Output:

```
0.0531250000000000
0.0531250000000000
0.0531250000000000
0.0531250000000000...
```

Comment: Note that `int(alpha)` is just zero. SymPy's integrate function performs symbolic integration so it shouldn't be necessary to call it in a loop like this. Just call integrate once in terms of symbolic limits and then substitute whatever values you want at the end.

Comment: Signature for `integrate(f, (x, a, b))`, where `f` is a sympy expression, `x` is a sympy symbol.  `s` is numpy array, so is `(t[k] - s) ** - int(alpha)`.  Neither is a valid argument for `integrate`.  Generally it does not work to mix `numpy` arrays and `sympy`.  Changing `s` to symbol (that's a BIG change), `(t[k] - s) ** - int(alpha)` is now a sympy expression.

Comment: With that `int(alpha)` your integral is just `t[i+1]-t[i]` which is `.0531` for a all `i` (given how `t` is constructed with `linspace`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you for warning me about `alpha`! I should not have used `int`. Actually, this integral is within a sum that has boundaries from i=0 to k-1. For this reason, I used loops to provide agreement with the sum and the whole equation. Still can I use your suggestion?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your explanations. I chose only `alpha` rather than `int(alpha)` because `alpha`s value is important for me. But I am a bit confused about your comment. What is the possible wrong part of my code?

Comment: Your first try with `s` as array gave you the ValueError.  The second try with `s` as symbol did work, given the constant differences between the `t` values.  In any case, trying to use numpy arrays with sympy is not helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SymPy you can get a symbolic expression:

```py
>>> var('s t e ti tj');i=integrate(1/(t-s)**e,(t,ti,tj));i
Piecewise(
((t - ti)**(1 - e)/(1 - e) - (t - tj)**(1 - e)/(1 - e),
   (e > -oo) & (e < oo) & Ne(e, 1)), 
(log(t - ti) - log(t - tj), 
   True))
```

With `e = -int(.99) = 0` -- are you sure that is what you want? -- this is

```py
>>> i0 = i.subs(e,-int(.99)); i0
-ti + tj
```

In this case, the integral does not depend on `t`, only the difference in the limits. As Oscar says, you can now just substitute in values of interest. Or, knowing that it is just the difference of points, you could compute those differences directly:

```py
>>> ts = [.85/16*_ for _ in range(17)]
>>> i0.subs({ti:ts[0], tj:ts[1]})
0.053125
>>> ts[1] - ts[0]
0.053125
```

This is the same that you got. You now (hopefully) understand why you were getting the same value every time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. It gave me a lot of information that I didn't have. No, I do not need the value of `int(.99) = 0` as I mentioned in the comments. I require the true value of `alpha` rather than `int(alpha)`. I fixed that mistake after Oscar's comment. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: OK, then that value of `i` is ready for substitution of any value of `alpha` (for which I used the symbol `e` for exponent), `ti` and `tj`.